# Check resource ownership on Node.js rest API

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose

I'm trying to develop a Node.js backend using express and mongoose.

Over the network there's plenty of examples of how to implement a proper **authentication** layer, but I couldn't find any example of how to correctly implement an **authorization** layer.

In my specific case, I'm creating the backend of a multi-user application and I want that every user can only see the data inserted by himself/herself.

I have three models:

1. User
2. Category
3. Document

**User** owns one or many **Categories**, **Categories** contain zero or more **Documents**.

The CRUD operations are implemented on the following endpoints:

```
/user/:userid
/user/:userid/category
/user/:userid/category/:categoryid
/user/:userid/category/:categoryid/document
/user/:userid/category/:categoryid/document/:documentid
```

In the authentication part I set to each request the current logged in user id, so I can check easily that

```
jsonwebtoken.userId == req.params.userid
```

And return a `403` error otherwise.

Checking the ownership of categories is quite easy, because each category contains a reference to the user who created them.

```
var CategorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    user_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        index: true
    }
});
```

In the Document model, however, I only have a reference to the category it belongs, but I didn't add a reference to the user.

I'm wondering therefore how to proceed with "nested" relationships. Do I need to add a `user_id` reference to all of them at any depth level? Is there any best practice?

Moreover, is this the right way to do what I need or is there any official/mature library that already does the same?

Comment: What you have here is an example of relational data. The solution isn't elegant in noSQL databases like mongo. 

I would just go with the route of adding "user_id" to the documents. This will prevent optimisation problems in the future.

Comment: @user1695032 thanks, I think it's better checking the ownership by `user_id`, otherwise I'd have to query Categories to see if the owner is `user_id` and only at that moment allow the user to create a new document, which kills performance. Seems weird to me that such basic use case is not documented or officially supported by a library though.

Answer (score 3):

Well no-sql database gives you the power of embedding your sub documents(or equivalent table in relational db) in to the single document. So you may consider redesigning your schema to something like

```
{
  userId:"",
  categories": [
    {
      "categoryId": "",
      "name": "",
      "documents": [
        {
          "documentId": "",

        },
        {
          "documentId": "",

        },

      ]
    },
    {
      "categoryId": "",
      "name": "",
      "documents": [
        {
          "documentId": "",

        },
        {
          "documentId": "",

        },

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This may help you optimize the number of db query but the important thing to note here is that if the number of categories and documents per user and per category repectively could grow very large then this approach would not be good.

Always remember 6 important thumb rules for mongo db schema design

1. Favor embedding unless there is a compelling reason not to
2. Needing to access an object on its own is a compelling reason not to embed it
3. Arrays should not grow without bound. If there are more than a couple of hundred documents on the “many” side, don’t embed them; if there are more than a few thousand documents on the “many” side, don’t use an array of ObjectID references. High-cardinality arrays are a compelling reason not to embed.
4. Don’t be afraid of application-level joins
5. Consider the write/read ratio when denormalizing. A field that will mostly be read and only seldom updated is a good candidate for denormalization.
6. You want to structure your data to match the ways that your application queries and updates it.

Taken from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3?_ga=2.70498838.769768791.1509799078-580389465.1509799078)

Comment: While this answer is really useful to decide how to design schemas, I don't think it actually solves the issues about how to verify "ownership" of a resource. It doesn't provide any pattern/best practice/library to achieve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering, I ended up with the following middleware.

It basically checks for route parameters in the expected order and checks for coherent memberships.

Not sure if it's the best way of achieving this, but it works:

```
var Category = require('../category/Category'),
    Document = require('../document/Document'),
    unauthorizedMessage = 'You are not authorized to perform this operation.',
    errorAuthorizationMessage = 'Something went wrong while validating authorizations.',
    notFoundMessage = ' not found.';

var isValidMongoId = function (id) {
    if (id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var verifyPermissions = function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.userId) {
        if (req.params.userid && isValidMongoId(req.params.userid)) {
            if (req.userId != req.params.userid) {
                return res.status(403).send({error: 403, message: unauthorizedMessage});
            }

            if (req.params.categoryid && isValidMongoId(req.params.userid)) {
                Category.findOne({_id: req.params.categoryid, user_id: req.params.userid}, function(err, category){
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).send({error: 500, message: errorAuthorizationMessage})
                    }
                    if (!category) {
                        return res.status(404).send({error: 404, message: 'Category' + notFoundMessage});
                    }

                    if (req.params.documentid && isValidMongoId(req.params.documentid)) {
                        Document.findOne({_id: req.params.documentid, category_id: req.params.categoryid}, function(err, document){
                            if (err) {
                                return res.status(500).send({error: 500, message: errorAuthorizationMessage})
                            }
                            if (!document) {
                                return res.status(404).send({error: 404, message: 'Document' + notFoundMessage});
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        next();
    } else {
        return res.status(403).send({error: 403, message: unauthorizedMessage});
    }
};

module.exports = verifyPermissions;
```

Comment: Does the category containes any more info apart from the name and userid?

Comment: @pulankit yes, the actual code has some more attributes stored in category (e.g. 'last opened', 'is active'). Moreover, I'm looking for a solution that works for nesting at each generic depth N.